# Understanding Perceptron training algorithm

Tags: matlab, neural-network, perceptron

The following text is from Hal Daumé III's ["*A Course in Machine Learning*"](http://ciml.info/dl/v0_9/ciml-v0_9-ch03.pdf) online text book (Page-41).

[image]

I understand that, `D` = size of the input vector.

(1) What kind of Perceptron algorithm is this? Binary/Multi-class? Online/Offline?

(2) What is `y` here? Bias/weight/Sample/class_label?

(3) What is the rationale of testing `ya<=0` for updating weights?

---

EDIT.

`y` is class_label.

Comment: You keep expanding the scope of the question, making older answers outdated. Not saying that this is not allowed, but you may be better off asking multiple questions. For instance, your fourth question, which you added a while after I posted an answer, could be a standalone question.

Comment: This question belongs to http://stats.stackexchange.com/ aka cross validated.

Comment: Do not vandalize your post.

Comment: I rolled back to revision 6 since the OP vandalized his post and before that expanded the scope of the question after an an answer was posted. This question needs to be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Answers to your questions:**

**1 -** This is a binary perceptron algorithm, working on an offline batch.

**2 -** as you wrote - Y is the labels vector. each label can be either be 1 or -1.

**3 -** The rational of testing if y*a<=0 is to check if the perceptron classified a certain sample correctly. If not - the weights of the perceptron are modified.

**A bit more about the 3rd question**

The idea behind the perceptron algorithm is as follows:

a. we iterate over the samples MaxIter times.

b. The perceptron classifies each sample by multiplying it with the weights vector W and adding a bias b. The result is assigned into the variable a.

c. The prediction for each sample can be either 1 or -1. It is calculated by sign(a). At this stage we check the correctness of the classification.

if y*a>0 that means that y=sign(a). In other words  the predicted classification is correct, and we move on to the next sample.

If however y*a<=0, that means that the perceptron failed to predict the correct label. In this case, the algorithm changes the perceptron's weights in a way that they'll be more compatible to the sample which we failed to classify.